# Extracting route config in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This may seem like a silly question, but I have looked all over the world wide interweb and can't find an answer.

I have a route configured in my application, thusly:

```
$routeProvider.when(
    "/customer/:customerId", {
        templateUrl: "/angular/components/booking-system/customers/templates/customer-template.html",
        controller: "customersCtrl"
    }
)
```

but I have no idea where to extract the customerId parameter in my customer-template.html. Can anyone shed some light on this? How do I access the parameter in code?

I am navigating to this route using:

```
   $scope.customerDetails = function(customerId) {
       $location.url("/customer/" + customerId);
   }
```

Is this the best way to navigate?

Comment: you could use ```$routeParams``` - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams and then one way of grabbing these would be if customers are in an array you could combine ```$routeParams``` with the ```$index```. This tutorial explains it quite nicely and simply https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ziUelciLL5Q

Comment: here is exactly what you are looking for: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$route

Comment: Hi @PaulFitzgerald; if you've answered the question instead of commenting I would've marked it as an answer. Thank a lot for the YouTube link!

Comment: @serlingpa it's not all about the points :-) glad it helped though, and hopefully now you understand it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access it in your controller like this:

```
 .controller('customersCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope,    
 $routeParams){
     $scope.customerId = $routeParams.customerId; //Make use of routeParams
 }])
```